# Is "vice-versa" to a dyslexic just plain redundant?

Tags: meaning

One of my friends asked me this question, but I really don't understand what it means. Please can someone explain it to me.

Comment: I've voted to close as "not a real question" because I don't get the question either.

Comment: rory has answered what i needed to know :)

Comment: I would understand this as an attempt at a joke - for the reason mentioned by Rory. A joke, I might add, that simplifies the condition somewhat! Akin to the "I'm a schizophrenic, and so am I", 'joke'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What your friend is saying is that as some dyslexics may have trouble with the order of letters or words, "vice-versa" is irrelevant to them as it means "in reverse order"

Obviously your friend isn't taking into account the variable extent of dyslexia in different individuals - many can read perfectly well, and others can given the use of systems to help identify letters and letter order.